# How do I use getschema for customDimensions?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, ms-app-analytics

I've used a query like

```
requests
| getschema
```

to get a table containing the names and types of all columns in the `requests` table. How can I get the same result for `requests.customDimensions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this can be done using [`buildschema`](https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Language-Reference/Aggregation-functions/buildschema()) and then transforming the output into a consumable format (thanks [Dmitry Matveev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4812747/dmitry-matveev) for helping me out with that piece ):

```
requests
| summarize schema=buildschema(customDimensions)
| mvexpand bagexpansion=array schema
| project name=schema[0], type=schema[1]
```